# Build project on a remote machine

Tags: java, build

I typically use Netbeans (but also STS) to develop my Java code but I've inherited an old laptop and actually like sitting on my sofa developing however it's to slow to run:

- Java based IDE (Netbeans/Eclipse)
- Database Server (Oracle XE)
- Oracle SQLDeveloper (Another Java Environment)
- Application Server (Tomcat/or Glassfish)
- Other little tools

I wanted to know if it would be possible to develop in my local IDE but to have my code built and deployed by a remote machine (desktop PC which is infinitely more powerful!!). If this were possible could you please suggest some tool, prefereably open source.

Comment: What is STS? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: STS is eclipse, by Spring Source

Comment: @Martijn STS stands for Springsource Tools Suite. It's an eclipse-based IDE optimized for Spring Development with a modified Tomcat that helps to see the inner working of a web app (Spring Insight). It also uses Spring Roo. Well, a Spring Tools SUite ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Fire up an SVN repo on your remote machine and have the code build when you check in using any number of continous integration tools(Hudson,Cruise Control, etc.).
2. FTP the code to a directory and use a CRON or scheduled task to periodically build out of that directory.
3. Install cygwin(windows) or just turn your machine on(linux) and script the deploy process in bash using `scp` or `sftp` for copy and execute an ant script over a remote shell.
4. Zip the code, put it on a flash drive, walk over to the desktop, insert flash drive, build and deploy

There are an infinite number of ways to do this, but they all follow the same pattern you need to get the code there(remote copy) and figure out a mechanism initiate the build process. There are tools which do this and afford varying degrees of complexity(Atlassian) that cost Tens of thousands of dollars and there are ways to accomplish the same end that cost $0, but require access to an editor and a little googling skill. Which one you choose is a matter of preference, materials at hand, and your requirements.

Comment: I like the idea of CI but do you know if it's possible to have Hudson etc build code which has not been submitted to a repository... I don't like the idea of having to submit code just because I'd like to build it!

Comment: Hudson has support for a number of triggers including Files Found in a directory, DOS Script, and various SCM repos. I'm not sure what the level of effort to set these other types of triggers are, but the overhead of the repo is almost nominal and the plugins pretty much work out of the box. Side note, almost any serious developer keeps an SCM repo even for their own pet projects. check out this URL for the trigger docs - http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/All+Plugins+by+Topic#AllPluginsbyTopic-Buildtools

Comment: Agreed, I have no problem using a repo (i have one setup already) however I only want it to contain code which is stable whereas using the repository method as outlined above I'd need to submit my code to the repo just to build the code... I'll look into the directory watcher triggers... cheers :-)

Comment: We have build a small tool called LiveSync which performs the sync on every file change via rsync. You simply start `livesync <virtual-machine>` in the project directory of your desktop. It will start watching for changes and push  them immediately to the remote. Hence you can code locally  and have all changes synced with your target system. With the `--on-change` parameter you can also trigger a rebuild on your target after each sync. - https://github.com/zauberzeug/livesync

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't put your server components on desktop machine and compile sources in laptop deploying WAR/JAR to remote server?

I think it would be much more simpler than other approaches. Netbeans works well in laptops in contrary to heavy server components.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a case for a remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at rmake https://github.com/ericwoodruff/rmake I'm sure you can configure your IDE to invoke a commandline tool (I've done it with Eclipse).